# .NET, ASHX, "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent" after sending PDF Streem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I visit my ASHX file, and it outputs a PDF perfectly.  If I visit the very same ASHX with a different query string (I append DateTime.Now.Ticks to the end each visit), and I get this error:

Server cannot append hader after HTTP headers have been sent.

My code is below:

```
copy.CloseStream = false;
document.Close();

var r = context.Response;
r.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
r.BufferOutput = true;
r.ContentType = "application/pdf";
r.AppendHeader("Content-Type", r.ContentType);
r.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + context.Server.UrlEncode(formType.File_Name));

r.BinaryWrite(copyStream.ToArray());
r.StatusCode = 200;
r.End();
originalReader.Close();
copy.CloseStream = true;
copy.Close();
```

There is no other place in this code that headers are sent.  You are seeing the entire interaction with the Response object.

I've tried to use `r.Flush();` and `r.End();`  I've also tried not sending them if they are already there, but this causes other issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with `r.StatusCode = 200;`, which corresponds to setting the header's first line.

Since this occurs after sending payload, this is unacceptable in HTTP protocol.

You have to do that earlier.

Comment: It looks like my problem was above the code the I showed here.  It turns out that my real issue was that I was using a WebRequest object in a Image event handler.  It wasn't in my ASHX but it was being used by my ASHX.  However, you were correct that the response code was in the wrong place as well!  Thanks so much!